# How to ALWAYS select the last item in the list

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to select the last item in a DYNAMIC list. The following is my script. Thanks!

```
WebElement selectElement = driver.findElement(By.name("siteKey"));
Select select = new Select(selectElement);
//select.selectByVisibleText("last item");
//select.selectByIndex(0);
//select.selectByValue("value");
```

Please see the page HTML below. Let me know if I can provide you with any other info. Thanks!

```
<div id="overview_form">
<ol>

<li>
<span>1.</span>
<label class="input_label" for="sites">Sites*</label>
<div class="select2-container select2-container-active select2-dropdown-    open" id="s2id_autogen1" style="width: 500px;">
<a tabindex="-1" class="select2-choice" onclick="return false;"     href="javascript:void(0)">   
<span>www.roger.com_20150210075155</span>
<abbr style="display:none;" class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   
<div><b></b></div></a>
<input type="text" class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" disabled="disabled">
</div>
<select style=" size="1" name="siteKey" class="select2-offscreen" tabindex="-1">

<option value="30518">www.roger.com_20150209191817</option>
<option value="30520">www.roger.com_20150209192123</option>
<option value="30522">www.roger.com_20150209192351</option>
<option value="30524">www.roger.com_20150209192910</option>
<option value="30528">www.roger.com_20150209193425</option>
<option value="30529">www.roger.com_20150209193801</option>
<option value="30531">www.roger.com_20150209194009</option>
<option value="30546">www.roger.com_20150210074133</option>
<option value="30548">www.roger.com_20150210074359</option>
<option value="30550">www.roger.com_20150210075155</option></select>

</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the source HTML look like?

Comment: What is exactly the error you are dealing with ?

Answer (score 3):

How about something like:

```
WebElement selectElement = driver.findElement(By.name("siteKey"));
Select select = new Select(selectElement);
select.selectByIndex(select.getOptions().size()-1);
```

Comment: When i run it, i get element is not visible

Comment: @familyGuy That is a different problem. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Different problem?, but the solution provided by Anna below does show an element we are trying to retrieve.

Comment: Anna's answer below is identical to mine, except the count is off by one.

Comment: just wanted to update you that the following code did the trick... By xpath = By.xpath("//div[@id='overview_form']//select/option[last()]");
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(xpath)); element.Click();

Answer (score 1):

You can use getOptions(), it will return a list then get the size of the list

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("siteKey")));
List<WebElement> l = select.getOptions(); 
int numElements = l.size();
select.selectByIndex(munElements);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: your approach seems pretty convincing. When I run it, it says "Cannot locate option with Index: 124. However, i do see the last option in the list as 124

Comment: `.size()` counts from one. `.selectByIndex()` starts from zero.

Comment: So, if i use this code, i get that "Element is not currently visible, so may not be interacted with:      Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("siteKey")));
 List<WebElement> l = select.getOptions(); 
 int numElements = l.size()-1;
 select.selectByIndex(numElements);            BUT, if I remove -1, then i get "Cannot locate option with Index: 124

Comment: Of course, it will throw the exception @familyGuy, because here the code is trying to get the element beyond the last index (as notified by @Siking). As per the error you are getting, there must be 124 options in the dropdown; hence the index of the options starts from **0 to 123**. Hence, the last element has the index of **123** that is 1 less than the total size of list of options. Therefore, it throws an exception because element having 124th index is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below way, and it's working.. Maybe this will help u .

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms11.htm");
    Thread.sleep(100l);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='dropdownmenu']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(100l);
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='dropdownmenu']"));
    List<WebElement> elements = element.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
    System.out.println(elements.get(elements.size() - 1).getText());
```